# Another: uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

K guys I'm working on a school project (in javascript) and I'm building a dungeon. Most likely not the best code you've ever seen but eh, I'm in school for that.

Im getting the error from:

```
function damageFormula()
{
    var damage = myDamage(myWeapon); // I get the error on this function
    var doDamage = Math.floor(0.085 * damage * myAttackLvl + (myLevelLvl/5) - (1+15*Math.random()));

    return doDamage;
};
```

The myDamage function:

```
function myDamage(myWeapon)
{
    switch(myWeapon)
    {
        case "Spike Sword":
            myDamage += 10;
            break;
        case "Magic Long Sword":
            myDamage += 20;
            break;
        default:
            myDamage += 3;
            break;
    }
    return myDamage;
};
```

The weapon variable is:

```
var myWeapon    = "Spike Sword";
```

And the myDamage variable is:

```
var myDamage    = 10;
```

Does anyone know why I get this error and/or how to solve it?

If you need more information, ask me anyting and I'll try to answer it as good as possible.

Comment: what is the line it's coming from :) ?

Comment: var damage = myDamage(myWeapon);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `myWeapon` is `Spike Sword`, you're doing this:

```
case "Spike Sword":
        myDamage += 10;
        break;
```

However, `myDamage()` is a function, not a number, so this doesn't make sense to the JavaScript console! Instead, it turns `myDamage` into a string and then puts `"10"` at the end of a string.

Now, `myDamage` is a string. However, in `damageFormula()`, you call `myDamage` as a function. Thus, a `TypeError` might be thrown, although for me,

I suggest doing `var damage = 0;` and doing `damage += 10;`, `damage += 20;`, etc..

Comment: Thanks alot! This is what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

Be wary of your names -- you use both `myDamage` as a name for a function **and** as a name for a variable ! This is going to create inconsistent state in your code.

You're probably using `var myDamage` somewhere else, making it null in the scope.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was wondering for hours why my code didn't work   :/